# Background task only called when activated in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

I have a backgroundservice thats polls for errors.

This background task only fires when I activate it while debugging.

[image]

Here is the registering of the service

[image]

and the service itself

[image]

Am i calling the service the wrong way? Why is it only firing when I activate it in Visual Studio ?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What interval are you using (in minutes)?

Comment: interval can be variable but is a minimum of 15

Comment: Did you declare the background task in the package manifest?

Comment: Task only fires when i activate it in visual studio ( first picture) can refire it multiple times. So if i could know what actually happens when i press it, i may solve my problem

Comment: yes the background task is declared

Comment: That should work. Stupid question but just in case: did you actually wait 15 minutes?

Comment: Yes i did only, one time tough .. can double check if you want ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87745/discussion-between-jeroen-brock-and-olivier-payen).

Comment: I want to draw your attention on some points.
1- You need to check after this line that access isn't denied
`var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

                if(result != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied)`

2- You are registering time trigger with OneShot property equals to true, It should be false in your case "polling".
`taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));`

3- If you are showing any toast, add Toast Capable in package Manifest, Do the same for Badge (If you are updating badge).

Answer (score 0):

I will add here some points I noticed which you need to consider in your code.

1-You need to check after this line that access isn't denied

```
var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();  
if(result   != BackgroundAccessStatus.Denied)
```

2- You are registering time trigger with OneShot property equals to true, It should be false in your case "polling" otherwise it will run only one time.

```
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
```

3- If you are showing any toast, add Toast Capable in package Manifest, Do the same for Badge (If you are updating badge).